# IF condition in Pine - assigning values based on different conditions

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to get the CCI value by using a variable with period/time-frame information in the built-in security function. The period/time-frame calculation in the IF condition below does not seem to be working: I am getting undeclared identifier message when I pass other_tf to security function.

Any expert input on smoothing out the CCI values on multiple time frames would also be appreciated :)

```
//@version=2
//This indicator will draw the following
//CCI-8 on current time frame/5 minutes
//CCI-34 on current time frame/5 minutes
//CCI-34 on higher time frame/30 minutes

study("Multi Timeframe CCI", shorttitle="MTF_CCI",overlay=false)
ccia_len = input(8, title="CCI A Length", type=integer)
ccib_len = input(34, title="CCI B Length", type=integer)
src = input(close, title="Source", type=source)


current_tf = period

if current_tf == '5'
    other_tf = '30'
if current_tf == '15'
    other_tf = '60'
if current_tf == '30'
    other_tf = '120'
if current_tf == '120'
    other_tf = 'D'


current_tf_ccia = cci(src,ccia_len)
current_tf_ccib = cci(src,ccib_len)
other_tf_ccib = security(tickerid, other_tf, cci(src,ccib_len))  
//other_tf_ccib = security(tickerid,"30",cci(src,ccib_len))

x1 = ema(other_tf_ccib,3)
other_tf_smoothccib = ema(x1,3)

plot(current_tf_ccia, color=red, title="CCI8 CTF")
plot(current_tf_ccib, color=green, title="CCI34 CTF")
plot(other_tf_ccib, color=black, title="CCI34 HTF")
plot(other_tf_smoothccib, color=yellow, title="CCI34 SMOOTH HTF")
```

Regards
Sharad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can work on an example here to see the problem.

What if `current_tf` is `'1'`? In that case, none of your if statements would be true so, it would skip all those ifs hence, `other_tf` would never get assigned to any value and therefore it would be undeclared (since you are only declaring that variable if one of your if statements is true).

You can declare it before you have your checks to prevent this error.

```
current_tf = period
other_tf = '1'

if current_tf == '5'
    other_tf := '30'
if current_tf == '15'
    other_tf := '60'
if current_tf == '30'
    other_tf := '120'
if current_tf == '120'
    other_tf := 'D'
```

Comment: `other_tf = '60'` won't work - you should use `:=` assign operator: `other_tf := '60'`. And I suppose default value of `other_tf = '1'`  would be better.

Comment: Thank you @Baris Yakut and Michel_T. After doing the suggested changes, I had a new problem that I could not pass a mutable variable to the security expression and I resolved that by wrapping the code in a function.